# My Private Sub in excel-vba gets en error, when I run it

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Tables. One of the Tables is linked to a XML-file. The other Table is here for searching data. The code in the Private Sub should work correctly, but when I want to run it, I get an Error.

Error while compiling:

Invalid identifier

The XML-Map is linked to that XML-File: http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=*

The Private Sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = [Name].Row And Target.Column = [Name].Column Then
        Dim Displayname As String: Displayname = [Name].Value
        Dim Map As XmlMap
        Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps
        Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "=http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname& * ""
        Map.DataBinding.Refresh
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I prevent the error, so that the Sub gets executet?

Comment: What line has the error? Also -- what is `& * ""` supposed to do? That `*` looks out of place. Is that supposed to be `& "*"`? If so, this question is just a typo and should be closed as such.

Comment: The Eror happens on the first Line. The & * "" is the search filter, which should work.

Comment: That `*` is occurring outside of a string literal, but you are trying to concatenate it to a string. That shouldn't work.

Comment: I used a tutorial for it and there it worked. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6H7tBL97orE

Comment: `xmlmaps` will work (I deleted that comment) -- but the `*` used outside of the string literal like that won't.

Comment: Also -- what is `Name`? Is this a named range in your worksheet?

Comment: But even when I delete the * it doesn't work, because the error is in line 1 at Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Yes, Name is a named range in my worksheet

Comment: *Where* is this code living? If it is in the worksheet code module (where it should be) then [Name] wouldn't be a valid qualifier. Just create a range variable and set it equal to that named range. Your line with `& *` had two typos: the `*` outside of `""` but also the lack of space before `&` in `Displayname& ` I suspect that you needed that line to end `Displayname & "*"`

Comment: Ok, now I fixed that, I couldn't use Name as you said. But now I have a new Problem. I get at the Dim Map As XmlMap a runtime error 13.

Comment: You are trying to set an `XmlMap` to an `XmlMaps` -- note the difference. The second is a collection type for the first.

Comment: This has become a different question. Perhaps post it as such. A Stack Overflow question shouldn't be an open thread that keeps mutating as you move through the debugging process.